# How to convert the whole object into Array without splitting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My array:

```json
{
  "address": "Baripada",
  "prime": "true",
  "time": "1290"
}
```

I need to change this into

```json
[
  {
    "address": "Baripada",
    "prime": "true",
    "time": "1290"
  }
]
```

I tried this:

```js
Object.entries(obj)
```

The output am getting is like

```
[
  [
    "address",
    "Baripada",
  ],
  [
    "prime",
    "true",
  ],
  [
    "prime",
    "1290",
  ]
]
```

How to get as a convert whole obj into single array?

Comment: you could wrap with an array, like `result = [object]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple ways, if you have such an object, wrap it in `[]`.

```js
const obj = {
  "address": "Baripada",
  "prime": "true",
  "time": "1290"
};

const arr = [obj];

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Aw, is that this simple ? Omg i was trying multiple ways ! Oh god

Comment: @samanthas Remember, JavaScript is written with duck-typed syntax! So everything is possible!  And it's simple too! And again, enjoy! Yes, some things are really simple.